# MVC3 error when trying to render action as partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I'm getting the following error when trying to use Html.Action to render a page as a partial view:

Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper

View code:

```
@Html.Action("Index", "Location", new { userId = 3428 })
```

Controller code:

```
public class Location : Controller
{
    private void PopulateDropdowns(LocationViewModel model, int userId)
    {
        var lookup = new AWS.BL.Lookup();

        model.Areas = lookup.GetAreas(userId);
        model.SEATs = new List<DTO.Lookup>();
        model.Establishments = new List<DTO.Lookup>();
        model.Properties = new List<DTO.Lookup>();
    }

    public ActionResult Index(int userId)
    {
        var model = new LocationViewModel();
        PopulateDropdowns(model, userId);
        return PartialView(model);
    }
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please include the full `exception` details

Comment: what happens if you visit the partial view directly? it should render the partial view correctly, but there could also be a problem in the view itself which causes the error.

Comment: I've just realised I've got my partial view in a subfolder in the shared folder so it can't find it! How do I get it to check subfolders? I've registered the subfolder like so: String[] NewPartialViewFormats = new[] { "~/Views/Shared/Partials/{0}.cshtml" };
base.PartialViewLocationFormats = base.PartialViewLocationFormats.Union(NewPartialViewFormats).ToArray();

Comment: Ignore that last comment. It's now working. Thanks.